# inheritance and declaration of functions c ++

Tags: c++, inheritance, declaration

I have 3 classes:

1. Class A
2. Class B
3. Class C

In `class A`, 2 methods are declared, one is `void`, the second is `virtual void`.
The `virtual void Method2` is defined in `class B`.
In `class C`, I call `Method1` and `Method2`;

As a result, I get the following error:

> error: 'void Base::A::Method1()' is inaccessible within this context
>
> error: 'Base::A' is not an accessible base of ‘Main::B’

```
namespace Base {
   class A {
   public:
      A() {}
      void Method1() {std::cout << "it is method1\n";}
      virtual void Method2() =0;
   }; // class A
} // namespace Base

namespace Main {
   class B : A {
   public:
      B() {}
      void Method2() {}
   }; // class B

   class C {
   public:
      C() {}
      void Handle() {
         b->Method1(); // it is good
         b->Method2(); // this is error
      }
   private:
      std::unique_ptr<B> b;
   }; // class C

} // namespace Main
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The error clearly states that the issue is with `Method1()`, the one you think is good. It's not implemented in this [mre], which explains why it's not compiling. You also don't properly scope your declaration of class A when inheriting. Is this a legitmate pattern, to namespace separate your base from the children? I'm not immediately seeing a benefit. Doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: Method 1 calls std::cout. I moved class A from Base to Main. Problem still exists.

Comment: Like I said about qualifying names: https://godbolt.org/z/3xWE6qfx6 Always worry about the first error.

Comment: Inheritance should be public to perform dynamic dispatch and type inclusion. `class B : public Base::A`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, Exactly! Thanks a lot!

What happens if you declare class A : B ?

Comment: Well it is a private inheritance, which is not related to type inclusion but a kind of pure inheritance, a *weird* way to implement a composition.

Comment: You did not provided a [mre]; you did not provide the information about compiler and compiler flags you use. I'm not even sure if the errors you quote are the whole information issued by the compiler. Without such information it is not clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You made two errors in one instruction, the declaration of class `B`. In the context of

```
namespace Base {
   class A {...}
}
```

this declaration

```
namespace Main {
   class B : A {
```

declares `B` as a class inheriting from `A` or some class in the current hierarchy of namespaces. The compiler will try `Main::A` and won't find it. It will then try the global namespace, `::A`, and will also fail to find `A` there. It will certainly won't try namespaces that are outside the current namespace hierarchy, in particular, it certainly *won't* try `Base::A`.  Having failed to find a class matching `A`, it will stop with an error.

The second error is in that you inherit the base class privately. This means that the information about this inheritance is invisible outside class `B`, so that you cannot call any of the base class members outside `B`.

Solution:

```
namespace Main {
   class B : public Base::A {
```